# Cant configure my router to open my site even if WAMP is put online

Tags: configuration, wamp, port, router

I have a problem, I have searched a lot on google and there are a lot of solutions but they are not for my router.

I have ZXV10 H201L router and when I visit my IP adress it gives me my router login panel.

I want it to open my wordpress website. I think its router configuring problem but I don't know how to configure this router, there are no information for it on internet.

Before this router I had another one and I could port forward it easily but this one I can't.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks:

http://prntscr.com/4tg68z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PortForward.com site](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/ZTE/ZXV10-H201L/radmin_-_Remote_Administrator.htm) has some help

However, as you say your problem is that when you use your Routers WAN ip address from your PC inside you local network you get the Router admin page. This is normally because most home/office routers do not have `loopback` configured or even available.

Without `loopback`, you cannot test your site using the WAN ip from inside your local network as the router has no way of recognising that the ip address you have used is its own ip address and looping you back inside your network transparently.

So to test external access to your site, use your phone or visit a friends and try from there. Basically you have to be coming at your router from the internet and not from inside your local network.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

On the link above, there is a section titled **Forward Ports 4899 on the ZTE ZXV10-H201L**

That is forwarding port 4899, where you see 4899 change it to 80 so you forward the routers port 80 to you PC's port 80.

Then where it says **LAN Host IP Address** enter the ip address of the PC inside your network that is running WAMPServer, something like 192.168.0.xxx probably.

If you dont know your PC's ip address do this from a command windows :-

```
ipconfig
```

In the output that creates, somehting like this, look for  :-

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd14:b968:af6f:1400:54c8:d12f:6bf1:f6ce
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fd14:b968:af6f:1400:49eb:b21e:15b1:b257
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::54c8:d12f:6bf1:f6ce%10
```

**This Following line>>**

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.11
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

Thats your PC's IP Address. Put the in the **LAN Host IP Address** field.

Comment: When i visit my IP address 77.28.215.*** it gives me the router login panel.When i visit my IP address 192.168.1.*** it gives me: Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server. I tried visiting both IP addresses with my smartphone it gives the same result. Also i tried the help from the website you recommended but i don't know how to configure it for 80 port, i don't know what to put inside those text boxes. If you could help me with that (how to fill in those boxes) it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Well until you work that out nothing you tried will work anyway. So thats your priority... learn to use your router.

Comment: I did the way you told me and now when i open my IP address 77.28.215.*** it gives me Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server. I think the router configuration is now correct thanks to your help but it doesn't have permission to access the root of server. How do i enable that?

Comment: I did a google search session using the right keywords and i found the answer of the last problem, i had to open httpd.conf and replace "Deny from all" to "Allow from all". Now i can open my website.

Comment: Be careful, especially as you have opened your system to the internet. The only place I can see that `Deny from all` exists is in the section that starts `<Directory />`. If you changed that to `Allow from all` then you just gave permission to any hacker that succesfully hacks your Apache to access the whole drive that Apache is installed on. Ask another question about the `Forbidden` issue so you can get the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, i did this only for few minutes for testing purposes, then i changed it back to Deny from all. Thanks again for all the help, i really appreciate it.